# Mercurial and the missing Visual Studio references

Tags: visual-studio, mercurial

I'm rather new to Mercurial and i've just started a project on bitbucket with TortoiseHg. My project in in Visual Studio 2010. I'm able to commit changes to the mercurial without problem but when my team mate pull the project from the mercurial to work on it he get's references missing error. I was wondering if this is a bad config in my project or a missing references on his side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files that are referenced in your project are not going to be included in Mercurial, unless those files are contained within the repository.

Your colleague can find which references are missing by expanding the`References` folder in the solution explorer, and seeing which ones have a yellow warning triangle on them. You might need to the copy those missing files over to their machine.

Another option would be to place those referenced files (if appropriate) into a directory within your repository, then remove the reference from the project and re-reference from the new location. Then the files are be added to the repository, although it could bloat the repository, so not ideal if using remote central repositories.

I would also recommend [VisualHG](http://visualhg.codeplex.com/) for Visual Studio to TortoiseHG integration, if you're not already aware of it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes i'm already using VisualHG as well. I will try to fix the references as you suggest and keep you posted.

Comment: @Hyrules - did you manage to get anywhere with this? Interested to know your progress

Comment: Yes the references was added to the project folder and  readded to the project and it fixed itself.

Comment: @Hyrules - great, glad to hear you got it sorted :-)